# Show image on click, modifying image positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

So, here's what I'm trying to do... I want to create a checklist, and when a box is checked, then the corresponding image appears (by default each image is set to hide). Here is the code that partially works:

http://jsfiddle.net/rpt8ck6L/1/

**HTML/Javascript:**

```
    <script>
        function toggleVisibility(id) {
            var el = document.getElementById(id);

            if (el.style.visibility == "visible") {
                el.style.visibility = "hidden";
            } else {
              el.style.visibility = "visible";
            }
         }
    </script>

<label for="001">001</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="001" onChange="toggleVisibility('img001');" />
<br/>
<label for="002">002</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="002" onChange="toggleVisibility('img002');" />
<hr/>
<div class="testclass">
    <img id="img001" src="http://tinyurl.com/n6amvuw" width="200" height="200" style="visibility:hidden" />
    <img id="img002" src="http://tinyurl.com/mm297df" width="200" height="200" style="visibility:hidden" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.testclass {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: relative;
}
.img001 {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
.img002 {
    border: 1px solid #0f0;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    top: -12px;
    left: 12px;
}
```

However, I also want the images to overlap one another, so that if two are checked, then the second one will appear on top. In order to have the images overlap, I was told that I had to use CSS styling (with z-index) and image CLASSES, instead of IDs.

So, I just changed the code to use className instead of ID:

http://jsfiddle.net/tbqm1yeo/

**HTML/Javascript:**

```
    <script>
    function toggleVisibility(className) {
        var el = document.getElementByClassName(className);

        if (el.style.visibility == "visible") {
            el.style.visibility = "hidden";
        } else {
            el.style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    }
</script>
<label for="001">001</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="001" onChange="toggleVisibility('img001');" />
<br/>
<label for="002">002</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="002" onChange="toggleVisibility('img002');" />
<hr/>
<div class="testclass">
    <img class="img001" src="http://tinyurl.com/n6amvuw" width="200" height="200" style="visibility:hidden" />
    <img class="img002" src="http://tinyurl.com/mm297df" width="200" height="200" style="visibility:hidden" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.testclass {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: relative;
}
.img001 {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
.img002 {
    border: 1px solid #0f0;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    top: -12px;
    left: 12px;
}
```

However, that didn't work (the images don't even appear when checkboxes are checked)... I'm assuming the problem has to do with using className? If someone could get the code from the second link working (so that the images will overlap and appear/disappear when checked), that would be great. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please edit your post to give it a useful title.

Comment: You have to use "document.getElementsByClassName". You used 'element' instead of 'elements'. document.getElementsByClassName will give you an array of dom objects matching with the classname.

Comment: Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tbqm1yeo/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix your problem just by using position `absolute`. Your original JavaScript is fine.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rpt8ck6L/2/

CSS:

```
#img001, #img002 {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    top:80px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:1;
}

#image002 { 
    z-index: 2 
}
```